# curl: option --connect-timeout: expected a proper numerical parameter

Tags: curl, kubuntu

**Update**: This was a bug which got fixed with version 7.87.0 https://github.com/curl/curl/commit/975efec61b83b840cf18ab2ee23b9202c60ca8a7

The accepted answer is still valid for prior versions, but it would be recommended to upgrade in order to ensure the scripts keep working after an automatic upgrade.

---

I have an issue with `curl` on two of my boxes. On around two dozens of Linux installations I'm having no problem with using fractional seconds in `curl --connect-timeout`.

The example command `curl --connect-timeout 3.14 https://example.com` is failing on only two of my machines, which are my only desktops, *my only Kubuntu installations*. The rest is mostly Ubuntu Server and a couple of Debian installations, all headless.

These two Kubuntu desktops differ in versions, one is an upgraded 22.04 LTS and the other a 20.04 LTS version.

The Kubuntu 22.04 has a `curl --version` of

```
curl 7.81.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.81.0 OpenSSL/3.0.2 zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.4.8 libidn2/2.3.2 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.2) libssh/0.9.6/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.43.0 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.5.13
Release-Date: 2022-01-05
```

The Kubuntu 20.04 has a `curl --version` of

```
curl 7.68.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.68.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1f zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 libidn2/2.2.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.2.0) libssh/0.9.3/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.40.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2020-01-08
```

For comparison, a working Ubuntu Server 20.04 has a `curl --version` of

```
curl 7.68.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.68.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1f zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 libidn2/2.2.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.2.0) libssh/0.9.3/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.40.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2020-01-08
```

which is identical to the output of Kubuntu 20.04's `curl --version`.

So the servers also have these versions installed, but there fractional seconds are working properly.

Both `curl --manual` yield the following grepped result:

```
~ curl --manual | grep -e "--connect-timeout"

    --connect-timeout <fractional seconds>
          curl --connect-timeout 20 https://example.com
          curl --connect-timeout 3.14 https://example.com
        See also --connect-timeout. Added in 7.47.0.
        See also -m, --max-time and --connect-timeout. Added in 7.59.0.
        See also --connect-timeout.
```

(on 20.04 is's a bit less verbose) so both are within the required versions to be able to deal with fractionals.

What could be causing this?

---

Another observation: I did a `md5sum` on the Kubuntu 20.04 and an Ubuntu 20.04 box and both return the same hash:

`c337f891e41007612076a3bc43284aa7  /usr/bin/curl`

so the executables are supposed to be identical.

`which curl` is returning `/usr/bin/curl` on both machines.

(Same goes for the 22.04 versions with `4b7b5099e836abd910f580808adc0874  /usr/bin/curl`)

Could the environment be causing this? How?

In all cases I checked this with `bash` and `zsh`.

Comment: What are the locales on the boxes in question? In particular, is the decimal point something other than `.` (`locale -k decimal_point`)?

Comment: That's it! Both Kubuntus have `LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"` while the other ones `LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"`. I set the OS language to `en_US` everywhere, but due to the crazy US date formatting in the UI's I set time (and with it the rest) to `de_DE`. I still need to confirm it, but I'm 99% certain that this is the problem.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks again. That fixed it. I added `export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"` to a couple of files (.profile and so on). Feel free to craft it as an answer so that I can accept it. An odd thing is that when using the "Formats -- System Settings" dialog to change the number format, even if it still shows the changed format after a reboot, `LC_NUMERIC` will still be at the wrong setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `curl` program appears to be locale-aware, which means that the conversion of strings to numbers will depend on the folllowing `LC_NUMERIC` values

```
decimal_point
thousands_sep
grouping
numeric-decimal-point-wc
numeric-thousands-sep-wc
numeric-codeset
```

In particular, in the `de_DE.UTF-8` locale, the decimal point character is `,` and `.` is the thousands separator:

```
$ LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8 locale -k LC_NUMERIC
decimal_point=","
thousands_sep="."
grouping=3;3
numeric-decimal-point-wc=44
numeric-thousands-sep-wc=46
numeric-codeset="UTF-8"
```

Hence in this locale, `3.14` is indeed not "a proper numerical parameter" - it would need to be written `3,14` . So

```
$ LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8" curl --connect-timeout 3.14 https://example.com >/dev/null
curl: option --connect-timeout: expected a proper numerical parameter
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

whereas

```
$ LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8" curl --connect-timeout 3,14 https://example.com >/dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1256  100  1256    0     0   4880      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4887
```

Comment: Thank you. I submitted this earlier today to the issue tracker and it turned out to be unwanted behavior which will be fixed in a future release. https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/9969